# How to efficiently calculate the sum and relative count frequency?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a one-line dplyr solution for filtering a data.frame on a score and afterwards calculating the relative count frequency.

The classic R solution would be the following:

```
daf <- data.frame(score=c(1:40),count=sample(1:1000,40,replace=T))
select <- daf$score >= 30
res <- c(sum(daf$count[select]),sum(daf$count[select])/sum(daf$count))
```

My first dplyr solution duplicates results:

```
daf %>% 
  mutate(total=sum(count)) %>% 
  filter(score >= 30) %>% 
  summarise(
    sum_count=sum(count),
    sum_rel=sum(count)/total
  )
```

Any better ideas for the dplyr code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `filter` the whole data frame to only sum the `count` values where the `score >= 30`. In this case, it's simpler to sum a subset of the `count` vector instead. And we can take advantage that `summarize` let's you use new columns immediately after defining them to get everything done inside a single `summarize`.

```
library(dplyr)
daf %>%
  summarize(
    sum_count = sum(count[score >= 30]), 
    sum_rel = sum_count / sum(count)
  )
#   sum_count  sum_rel
# 1      5661 0.301053
```

As well as being less typing than a `filter` approach, this is faster too. However, with a this simple of an operation `base` R is still twice as fast as this method, even on decent-sized data:

```
set.seed(47)
n = 1e5
daf <- data.frame(score=c(1:100),count=sample(1:1000,n,replace=T))


library(dplyr)
bench::mark(
  op = {
    select <- daf$score >= 30
    res <- c(sum(daf$count[select]),sum(daf$count[select])/sum(daf$count))
  },
  gregor = daf %>%
    summarize(
      sum_count = sum(count[score >= 30]), 
      sum_rel = sum_count / sum(count)
    ),
  caz_max = daf %>%
  mutate(total = sum(count)) %>%
  filter(score >= 30) %>%
  summarise(sum_count = sum(count),
            sum_rel = sum(count) / max(total)),
  caz_first = daf %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(count)) %>%
  filter(score >= 30) %>%
  summarise(sum_count = sum(count),
            sum_rel = sum(count) / first(total)),
  check = FALSE
)
```

```
# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time 
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis>
# 1 op           1.07ms   2.02ms     457.     2.23MB    29.6    139     9      304ms <NULL> <Rpro… <ben…
# 2 gregor       2.87ms   5.53ms     153.     1.31MB     4.63    66     2      432ms <NULL> <Rpro… <ben…
# 3 caz_max      7.94ms  11.42ms      83.6       3MB     4.52    37     2      442ms <NULL> <Rpro… <ben…
# 4 caz_first    6.31ms   8.49ms     112.        3MB    12.7     44     5      394ms <NULL> <Rpro… <ben…
# # … with 1 more variable: gc <list>
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? (Came up in the LQA queue)

Comment: @camille thanks for the head's up! Much improved now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `total` column will always be the same value, use `max(total)` instead of `total` in `summarise`:

```
daf %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(count)) %>%
  filter(score >= 30) %>%
  summarise(sum_count = sum(count),
            sum_rel = sum(count) / max(total))

  sum_count   sum_rel
1      5535 0.2621608
```

**Edit:** As per @GregorThomas's comment, using `first()` instead of `max()` would be more efficient for large data sets.

```
daf %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(count)) %>%
  filter(score >= 30) %>%
  summarise(sum_count = sum(count),
            sum_rel = sum(count) / first(total))
```

Comment: What's the benefit in using `max(total)` instead of `total`?

Comment: The denominator for `sum_rel` is a scaler value rather than a vector, so the output contains a single row as above, rather than multiple rows that repeat themselves.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. When OP said their code "duplicates results", I thought they were just saying that it reproduced the `res` result of their base R code, now I see they were identifying repeated rows as a problem. `first()` would be more efficient than `max()` here, as it doesn't require any comparisons.

Comment: You're right. Posted an update to the code as an edit.